# Finding exact solutions of an equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the question "Find the exact solutions of the following equation, giving your answer in terms of i and simplifying any surds (where possible):

2X^2 + 8X + 9 = 0"

Here is my attempt is this correct ?

[image]

Comment: *"Is this correct?"* You can check that by simply plugging in your solutions into $2x^2+8x+9=0$.

Comment: You have omitted a $4$ in the second step in the left.

Comment: And not $\sqrt{i}$ on 7th line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. Just a couple of notes in the picture below

Hope this is useful

*Edit*

Verify the solution

$$2 \left(-2-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+8 \left(-2-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+9=2\left(4+\frac{4i}{\sqrt 2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)-16-\frac{8i}{\sqrt 2}+9=$$
$$=8+\frac{8i}{\sqrt 2}-1-16-\frac{8i}{\sqrt 2}+9=0$$

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the corrections :)

Comment: Can I just ask how you would put this value into the equation given to equal 0 ? Because when I put this in the equation I get 2 ? Thanks :)

Comment: @Dan I added the calculations to get 0 to my answer. Have a look

Comment: Thanks so much really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct to me. Here's how I would do it though:

$$
2x^2 + 8x + 9 = 0\implies\\
x^2 + 4x + \frac{9}{2} = 0\implies\\
x^2+2\cdot x\cdot 2+2^2-2^2 +\frac{9}{2} = 0\implies\\
(x+2)^2=\frac{8}{2}-\frac{9}{2}\implies\\
(x+2)^2=-\frac{1}{2}\implies\\
x_{1,2}+2=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}}\implies\\
x_{1,2}=-2\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\cdot (-1)}\implies\\
x_{1,2}=-2\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\cdot i^2}\implies\\
x_{1,2}=-2\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\sqrt{i^2}\implies\\
x_{1,2}=-2\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\implies\\
x_{1,2}=-2\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i
$$

Comment: Thanks really helpful :)